# How can I restore the password in xubuntu 18.04.1, by not finding the rw command at startup?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

In grub, type "e" adding "rw init = / bin / bash" in the last line but say "can not find the order rw" and the same.

Comment: The command to add is just `init=/bin/bash`. The `rw` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can change you password under `chroot` mode.

Enter chroot mode by:
    - `sudo mount -o /dev/sdxX /mnt` where xX is you drive and partition number where a root partition is;
    - `sudo mount /dev/sdxX /mnt/boot/efi` if your system is installed in EFI mode;
    - `for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /run /sys; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done`;
    - `sudo chroot /mnt`;
    - `for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /run /sys; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done`;
    - `sudo chroot /mnt`.
Now run `passwd` and change the password.